# Insert into post or

Tags: uploads, media-modal

I am about to delve into wp media upload/edit code, I want to add another option where you can insert into post I want to add a use as title graphic option. Hoping someone may have braced this before and can maybe save me some time and stress. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like a featured image?

Comment: I wish I could have used a featured image, but no, I mean in the actual modal window where you add the image, set its size, where it links to, alt tag etc, and then you have the insert into post link, which fires the window.sendToEditor() function we all love. I was wanting to add another link beside insert into post, saying Use as title graphic

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, it sounds like your 'title graphic' is in effect a second featured image, so could you not use a plugin like [Multiple Post Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/)? If I've misunderstood, can you explain a bit more clearly what you mean by 'title graphic'?

Comment: Liam: Additional info as [edit] - always - please.